# Ruby: Get consecutive pairs of elements from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given the array: `[1,2,3,4]` I would like to receive an array back of `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]`.

Is there a one-liner or a method that does this?

Comment: BTW it's not an array of all the pairs (i.e. 2-element combinations), it's an array with all consecutive pairs.

Comment: @MarekLipka Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: By the way, it would help tremendously, what the problem is with the documentation of `Enumerable#each_cons` or `Enumerable` in general that prevented you from finding this method. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't have this problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the primary problem is that I didn't know the concept of "consecutive". Not a fault on anyone but my lack of experience.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), passing 2 as argument:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each_cons(2).to_a
# [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

You need to use `to_a` there, because each_cons by itself returns an Enumerator object.