# How to split each 2 word in string into array - Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, split

I want to split a string to an array which include each 2 word of original string as below:

```
Ex:
str = "how are you to day"
output = ["how are", "are you", "you to", "to day"]
```

Any one can give solution? thank so much!

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004542/ruby-get-consecutive-pairs-of-elements-from-an-array ‘’’
str.split.each_cons(2).to_a
‘’’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input

```
str = "how are you to day"
```

Code

```
p str.split(/\s/)
     .each_cons(2)
     .map { |str| str.join(" ") }
```

Output

```
["how are", "are you", "you to", "to day"]
```

Comment: Is the “map(:&itself)” basically the same as calling “to_a”?

Comment: @melcher No! `map(&:itself) = map{|x| x}`

Comment: @melcher I am realizing now that `map(&:itself)` is not necessary in my above code.

Comment: The split argument isn’t really necessary for the example given.

Comment: @Michael B How come ? I am splitting and converting into array first, that is very much necessary!

Comment: `split` returns an array. You can save memory by returning an enumerator if you replace `str.split(/\s/)` (or just `str.split`) with  `gsub(/\w+/)`.

Comment: @Rajagopalan The ```split``` method is necessary.  Its the argument (```(/\s/)```) that is unnecessary.  The ```split``` method will split on whitespace (equivalent to ```" "```) if no argument is given.  Based on the example string, I see no need to run the extra regex.

Comment: @Rajagopalan and @Cary Swoveland, Just running some quick benchmarks and just FYI, all other things being equal, using ```str.split``` is the fastest.  ```str.split(/\s/)``` takes about 60% longer to execute, and using ```gsub(/\w+/)``` takes about 140% longer to execute.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, you're welcome.  Nothing against your suggested approach at all, but for what its worth, the alternative method I posted below is about 20% faster than even using ```str.split``` in your suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, which uses a regex trick to duplicate the second through second to last words in the input string:

```rb
input = "how are you to day"
input = input.gsub(/(?<=\s)(\w+)(?=\s)/, "\\1 \\1")
output = input.scan(/\w+ \w+/).flatten
puts output
```

This prints:

```
how are
are you
you to
to day
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ways to do that. Both use the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a regular expression as its argument and no block, returning an enumerator. This form of `gsub` merely generates matches of the regular expression; it has nothing to do with string replacement.

```
str = "how are you to day"
```

**Use a regular expression that contains a positive lookahead**

```
r = /\w+(?=( \w+))/
str.gsub(r).with_object([]) { |s,a| a << s + $1 }
  #=> ["how are", "are you", "you to", "to day"]
```

I've chained the enumerator `str.gsub(r)` to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object). `String#gsub` is a convenient replacement for `String#scan` when the regular expression contains capture groups. See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) for for an explanation of how it treats capture groups.

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    \w+       # match >= 1 word characters
    (?=       # begin a positive lookahead
      ( \w+)  # match a space followed by >= 1 word characters and save
              # to capture group 1
    )         # end positive lookahead
    /x        # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

**Enumerate pairs of successive words in the sting**

```
enum = str.gsub(/\w+/)
loop.with_object([]) do |_,a|
  a << enum.next + ' ' + enum.peek
end
  #=> ["how are", "are you", "you to", "to day"]
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek). After `next` returns the last word in the string `peek` raises a `StopIteration` exception which is handled by `loop` by breaking out of the loop and returning the array `a`. See [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).

Comment: You are the real master in Ruby!

Comment: @Rajagopalan, thanks, but you are misguided! I'm just a Ruby hobbiest.

Comment: That's why you are more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another option:

```
str = "how are you to day"
arr = str.split
new_arr = []
(arr.length-1).times {new_arr.push(arr[0..1].join(" ")); arr.shift}

print new_arr #=> ["how are", "are you", "you to", "to day"]
```

Comment: ...or drop `new_arr = []` and replace the next line with `(arr.length-1).times.map { |i| arr[i] + ' ' + arr[i+1] }`.